# how to make a random list in python3

Tags: python, dictionary

i just want make a list to display  students scores  and different course have different scores ,the scores comes from.random randint(70,100), like this:

```
[{'C++':70,'Math':80,'Python':90},
{'C++':87,'Math':82,'Python':91},...]

import random
def makedict(spam):
    a=[]
    for j in range(20):             
        for i in spam:
        a[j].setdefault(i,random.randint(70,90))
    return a
if __name__=="__main__":
    cou=['C++','Math',Python]
    res=makedict(cou)
```

IndexError: list index out of range
how i change the code

Comment: use `a.append` instead of indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, You have to use `append`.

```
import random
def makedict(spam):
    result = []
    for _ in range(20):
        result.append({j:random.randint(70,90) for j in spam})
    return result

if __name__=="__main__":
    cou=['C++','Math', 'Python']
    res=makedict(cou)
```

Comment: i also use append,but i don't know {j:random.randint(70,90) for j in spam},so it's good for me to learn

Answer (score 2):

use dictionary comprehension

```
import random
def makedict(subjects):
    return {s: random.randint(70,100) for s in subjects}

if __name__=="__main__":
    cou=['C++','Math','Python']
    res=makedict(cou)
```

Comment: i want to make more than one dictionary,so your answer is also good if add a loop

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation for the second for..loop is wrong. Fix it and it will work.